# Cannot open .cshtml files with Visual Studio 2015 PRO

Tags: visual-studio, razor

I cannot open .cshtml files with visual studio 2015 PRO. It gives me the error that the file has been moved or deleted. But I can open the file with visual studio express 2015 for web. Why is this?

Comment: Close VS and open again and try it. May be clean the solution ?

Comment: @Shyju I have tried that. I have also tried repairing and re-installing VS 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only that worked for me was to re-installing Windows 10.  I tried everything I could find on Stack Overflow and on the MSDN forums.